# change event on multiple text box in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and each row of the table has a checkbox, textbox and name field. 
Following is the html

```html
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="visible" id="soil_row_cb" checked></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="position" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="NA"></td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="factor" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="NA"></td>
</tr>
```

i want to read the value as soon as it is entered in any of the text box with name = **position** 
[image]

Comment: where you want to read...

Comment: in the js file i want the value entered in any of the text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Have a look

```js
$("input[name='position']").keyup(function() {

  var valueOfInput = $(this).val(); //value
  var indexOfTr = $(this).parents('tr').index(); //index

  console.log(valueOfInput, '-->', indexOfTr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="visible" id="soil_row_cb" checked></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="position" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="NA" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="position" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="w" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="visible" id="soil_row_cb" checked></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="position" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="s" /></td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you sukesh ...and if i  have multiple text box in the same tr

`<tr>    
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="visible" id="soil_row_cb" checked></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="position" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="NA"/</td>
<td><input type="text" name="factor" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="NA"/</td>
    <td>Name</td>
</tr>
`            **how can i select the value with name=position textbox ?**

Comment: I have updated the code in snippet you can value by 
$(this).find("input[name='position']").val()

Comment: for me i get the value as **undefined,3,2,1**. 
In your snippet too when i edit the value i get in the table below as **undefined, 1, 1**

Answer (score 0):

you can use name as array and make common class name for input field...

hope it work...

```js
 $('.myclassname').on("keyup",function(){
        var row_index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        // row_index = row_index-1; // if you have tr header then enable this also...
        var textvalue = $("[name='position[]']").eq(row_index).val();
        alert(textvalue);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="visible" id="soil_row_cb" checked></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="position[]" class="myclassname" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="NA" /></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="visible" id="soil_row_cb" checked></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="position[]" class="myclassname" style="text-align: center;" maxlength="3" size="3" value="s" /></td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```